# Form elements as arrays in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

Using Drupal 6.20.

We can setup some form elements like this:-

```
<input type="select" name="somename[]"><option>ohai</option></select>
```

and then cycle through them in PHP with

```
foreach ($somename as $name) { ... }
```

I am trying to do the same in Drupal. I have a list of `select-elements` that are identical in style. The number of elements may change in the future so the form processing has to be dynamic.

If I use the above approach, each element will overwrite the preceding one, so that ultimately only one element is printed to the screen. I can't write `name="somename[$someid]"` as that will not interpret `$somename` as an array.
 Does Drupal support this or am I doing it worng?

Also, Is there any other alternative to achieve the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
function test_form( &$form_state )
{
  $form = array();
  $delta = 0;
  $form["test_field"]["#tree"] = TRUE;
  $form["test_field"][$delta++] = array(
        "#type" => "textfield",
        "#title" => "Title",
    );
  $form["test_field"][$delta++] = array(
        "#type" => "textfield",
        "#title" => "Title",
    );
  $form["test_field"][$delta++] = array(
        "#type" => "textfield",
        "#title" => "Title",
    );
  $form["submit"] = array(
        "#type" => "submit",
        "#value" => "Submit",
    );
  return $form;
}
```

In your submit & validate function, you will get an array of values under your field's name.

Remember, enabling #tree on your element is the key to this approach. Also Drupal's form API is one of the best forms framework I have worked with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wish i had seen this before putting _1 on the initial form field name, then increment that with the new javascript created ones thru string manipulation...bleh...

Answer (score 3):

I know this question was answered but I think there's an easier way which is less verbose and you only need to change the number of fields (or pass it as an argument when getting the form).

```
function test_form() 
{
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE; // This is to prevent flattening the form value
    $no_of_fields = 5;     // The number of fields you wish to have in the form

    // Start adding the fields to the form
    for ($i=1; $i<=$no_of_fields; $i++)
    {
        $form['somename'][$i] = array(
            '#title' => t('Test field no. '.$i),
            '#type'  => 'textfield',
        );      
    }
    // Add the submit button
    $form["submit"] = array(
        "#type"  => "submit",
        "#value" => "Submit",
    );  
}
```

When submitting your $form_state['values'] will contain (among other things) your form elements value as an array:

```
  'somename' => 
    array
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
      5 => string '' (length=0)
```